# Ensuring a unique number to identify something

Tags: ruby, uniqueidentifier

I built a shopping cart. One of them is paypal standard which requires unique invoice integer. From the shopping cart, I just use the id of the current cart. However, the user can reactivate the service from within the web application itself (which is independent of the shopping cart site). This means I need a unique number and cannot rely on cart id, since the application itself has no cart. So I am thinking to take the current datetime in ruby and convert it to an integer:

```
DateTime.now.to_i 
=> 1370617672

DateTime.now.to_i
=> 1370617700
```

Will this guarantee a unique number always (since datetime is always changing). And if not, what other option would I have?

Comment: How big can that integer be?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev whatever paypal allows for their invoice integer, which Im having difficulty finding out on google

Comment: I have no idea either. Does it have to be integer, or you can use arbitrary string?

Comment: Maybe a string will work. I was just using the cart id before, which is an integer.

Comment: Using DateTime to guarantee uniqueness is not a guarantee. Two users could click at the same instance, or two instances of the application could fire off at the same time. It's a slim chance, but do you want to explain to a customer why they just got billed for the items in someone else's cart? Go with a string. There's no point in storing a number if you're not going to do math with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need unique identifier, you should make such. For example, [`SecureRandom.uuid`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid):

```
p SecureRandom.uuid #=> "2d931510-d99f-494a-8c67-87feb05e1594"
```

(I assume that PayPal accepts arbitrary strings and doesn't require actual integers)

Comment: This is pretty much guaranteed to be unique. Current time does not offer such guarantees. It has resolution up to a second, so two invoices of the same second will have same ids.

Comment: Removing the artificial use of `to_i`, Time has `.usec` precision, and DateTime has `%N` inside `strftime`, so resolution is well beyond a second, but still there's a chance of collision. UUID is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @theTinMan: yeah, it's actionscript that has second precision. I need to rest more. :)

Comment: Rest is always good. Your point is dead on though, a UUID has guaranteed uniqueness (though I still don't understand how we can speak for the rest of the universe... I think that's human ego).